# Join with aggregate

Tags: sql-server, join

[image: SQL Server Interview Question]

I faced a question in interview like this. The output will contain the each ID highest age with highest mark.

Comment: what should be result if data like  2 30 200 and 2 28 300?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` WITH `PARTITION BY` as below to get your output

```
;WITH T AS
(
    SELECT
        ID,
        Age,
        Marks,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Age DESC,MArks DESC) AS PartNo
    FROM @tbl1
)
SELECT
    T.ID,
    T2.Name,
    T.Age,
    T.Marks
FROM T
LEFT JOIN @tbl2 T2 ON T.ID=T2.ID
WHERE PartNo=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.ID,A.Name,MA.MaxAge Age,MM.MaxMarks Marks FROM tbl2 A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Id, Max(Age)MaxAge FROM tbl1 GROUP BY ID) MA ON MA.ID = a.ID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Id, Max(Marks)MaxMarks FROM tbl1 GROUP BY ID) MM ON MM.ID = a.ID
```

Use this query, you will get your result